# Event Aggregration between WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, aggregation

I have one silverlight application hosted in WPF environment.

i have created one static eventaggregrator class. 
which is used between multiple modules hosted using prism.

but for the event which need to be publish **from** a module developed in **WPF** and subscribe in the module developed **in** **silverlight**.

**is it possible?** if yes then can anybody give me some ref article or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF and Silverlight use different execution environments, so code cannot be shared at runtime.

If you are hosting the Silverlight control inside a WebBrowser control in WPF then you will have to insert a Javascript layer inbetween your Silverlight control and the WPF host.

So you will subscribe in the .NET world, and then use the InvokeScript() method on your WebBrowser control to invoke a Javascript script which can communicate with the Silverlight control (see ScriptableMember).

Comment: Thanks Philipp i'll check ScriptableMember and try to implement it.